# MVC Losing data while filling out form on webpage

Tags: c#, controller

The problem is whenever i click the submit button, my program forgets all the data the user has written into the textboxes. The "Ressurs" list also never goes above the count of 2.

My controller:

```
    const string SESSION_SAVED_MODEL = "savedModel";

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL] = new EmailFormModel();


        return View(Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL]);
    }




    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(EmailFormModel model)
    {



        if (Request.Params["Ekstra_Ressurs"] != null)
        {
            model.Ressurs.Add(new EmailFormModel.RessursBehov());
            Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL] = model;

        }

        return View(model);

    }
 }
 }
```

My model:

```
public class EmailFormModel
{
    public EmailFormModel()
    {
        Ressurs = new List<RessursBehov>() { new RessursBehov() };
    }


    public List<RessursBehov> Ressurs;

    public class RessursBehov
    {

        [Required, Display(Name = "Antall timer")]
        public int? Antall_Timer { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Antall uker")]
        public int? Antall_Uker { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

My index (in Views/app):

### Index

```
@model Debug.Models.EmailFormModel


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Ressurs.Count; i++)
{


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Timer, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Timer, new { @class = "html_label" })


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Uker, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Uker, new { @class = "html_label" })

                </div>
            </div>
}

<div class="col-md-5"></div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Legg til ressurser" name="Ekstra_Ressurs" />
</div>
}
```

Comment: try using '@using (Html.BeginForm()) instead of '@Html.BeginForm, and also m => m.Ressurs[i] instead of m => Model.Ressurs[i]

Comment: One thing that worked for me is putting the action/controller name in the beginform, ie Html.BeginForm("Index", "<Controller>", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: Yes, @using (Html.BeginForm()) is necessary for the program to even compile. Whether i use m => m.Ressurs[i] or m => Model.Ressurs[i] seem makes no difference. Filling the Html.BeginForm makes no difference either.

Comment: OK, as nobody else seems to be helping out here, and I've got a few minutes I'll set up an MVC project, copy and paste your code and see what's going on. I have done something almost identical to this and it's all working and I can't see any obvious flaws in your code. I'll let you know how I get on :)

Comment: OK, got it working, will post the answer below

Answer (score 0):

For some reason making it an IList on it's own works.
I'll look into it some more, but for now a working solution:
First the controller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        const string SESSION_SAVED_MODEL = "savedModel";

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL] = new List<RessursBehov> { new RessursBehov() };


            return View(Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL]);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(IList<RessursBehov> model)
        {



             if (Request.Params["Ekstra_Ressurs"] != null)
            {
                model.Add(new RessursBehov());
                Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL] = model;

            }

            return View(model);

        }

    }

    public class RessursBehov
    {

        [Required, Display(Name = "Antall timer")]
        public int? Antall_Timer { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Antall uker")]
        public int? Antall_Uker { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then the View

```
@model IList<WebApplication1.Controllers.RessursBehov>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].Antall_Timer, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Antall_Timer, new { @class = "html_label" })


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].Antall_Uker, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Antall_Uker, new { @class = "html_label" })

            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Legg til ressurser" name="Ekstra_Ressurs" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help, its greatly appreciated!
However i don't know if that type of solution would really benefit me. I want to store all the inputs from some dynamic form on my webpage and then send it off either as an email or to a database. The most practical way (as i could think of) would be to store all the inputs in a class. But the problem is that there is a different amount of inputs in the different fields. So I end up with a nested group of classes. It seems like this would be a pain to do in the controller. I would like to organize it from the model.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, as I intimated in my answer, I'll look at it again tomorrow if we don't get a definitive answer here. There is a way that I do it by serializing the form, but it's not pretty and there must be a better way, let's hope we come back tomorrow and one of the clever people on here has shown us something that is probably pretty obvious that we are both missing :)